# div *ngIf="is_auto===false" is not showing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-ng-if

I have two segments. When 'Manual' segment is selected, "is not auto" is not showing but instead showing as "is auto" although the value of {{is_auto}} is false

```
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="is_auto">
    <ion-segment-button mode="md" [value]="true">
        <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button mode="md" [value]="false">
        <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

{{is_auto}}
<div *ngIf="is_auto === false">
    is not auto
</div>
<div *ngIf="is_auto">
    is auto
</div>
```

When 'Auto' segment is selected, output is

> true

> is auto

When 'Manual' segment is selected, output is

> false

> is auto

I have imported Browser Module and Common Module.

**UPDATE**

> The variable is cast as a boolean, but ion-segment keeps getting away
> with converting it to a string. ionic 3 works fine but not with ionic
> 4

**SOLVED**

cast the variable as string as ionic 4 ion-segment seems to handle all value as string

Comment: Make sure your ngIf expressions are within double quotes, like `*ngIf="is_auto"` instead of single quotes `*ngIf='is_auto'`

Comment: even changed to double quote is still the same

Comment: you can simply use `*ngIf="!is_auto"` . also check the variable as well that what value you are getting.

Comment: *ngIf="!is_auto" is not working either, and the value for the variable {{is_auto}} is return as true or false

Comment: @ShamPooSham _"Make sure your ngIf expressions are within double quotes"_ Why?

Comment: @unknown Ok. Can you see what you get if you do `{{typeof is_auto}}`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Because it's the correct syntax. I've had issues with it before, I was thinking it might be the problem

Comment: @ShamPooSham I'm pretty sure there is no _"correct syntax"_ regarding the quotes. Do you have a reference for this? It's possible that there where bugs in Angular 2 5 years ago.

Comment: the type of is_auto is boolean

Comment: @unknown can you show some ts code is the variable private ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ok, I'm sorry I was probably wrong. Just trying different things to see if it helps.

Comment: @unknown is the output of `typeof is_auto` "`boolean`"? Because typescript can be tricky with this. Just because you have declared something a certain type, it's not certain it has that type. This is especially true if you do http calls.

Comment: @unknown `is_auto` is string not Boolean so you have to use `*ngIf="is_auto === 'false'"` instead of *ngIf="is_auto === false"

Comment: I'm curious. Did you solve it?

Comment: I’m very sure that is_auto is Boolean as when I tried to compare it as string, it will show error and saying that is_auto is Boolean

Comment: @ShamPooSham typeof is_auto in constructor returns boolean, but on segment changed event, typeof is_auto returns string

Comment: @unknown There you go, ion-segment will stringify the values. I will make a response with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngIf="is_auto;else elsepart">
    this is true part
</div>

<ng-template #elsepart> 
   ---- this is false part
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Both ways are fine, this won't solve OP's problem

Comment: has to declare is_auto:boolean = false;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: typeof is_auto in constructor returns boolean, but on segment changed event, typeof is_auto returns string

Answer (score 0):

The value type `is_auto` received is string, not boolean. So compare it with string instead:

```
<div *ngIf="is_auto === 'false'">
    is not auto
</div>
<div *ngIf="is_auto === 'true'">
    is auto
</div>
```

Comment: i just confirm value type is_auto received is boolean

Comment: typeof is_auto in constructor returns boolean, but on segment changed event, typeof is_auto returns string

Comment: Sure it is, value type  from html inputs is string, except input type number have it value type as number

Answer (score 0):

Because `ion-segment` will stringify your value, you have to handle that in some way. You could parse `is_auto`, but I think a better solution would be to use a union type variable instead, like this:

Typescript:

```
mode: "auto" | "manual";
```

HTML:

```
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="mode">
    <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="auto">
        <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="manual">
        <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div *ngIf="mode === 'auto'">
    is auto
</div>
<div *ngIf="mode === 'manual'">
    is not auto
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Quotemarks "" instead of single quotemarks.

Also you can use !is_auto

```html
<div *ngIf="!is_auto">
    is not auto
</div>
<div *ngIf="is_auto">
    is auto
</div>
```

[Stackbitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxf6zy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

trey below code

`html code`

```
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="is_auto">
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" [value]="true">
        <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" [value]="false">
        <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    {{is_auto}}
    <div *ngIf="is_auto === 'false'">
      is not auto
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="is_auto === 'true'">
      is auto
    </div>
```

`ts code`

public is_auto;

Answer (score -1):

Do not use boolean value.

```
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="is_auto">
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="first">
      <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="last">
      <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

  {{is_auto}}
<div *ngIf="is_auto == 'first'">
  is not auto
</div>
<div *ngIf="is_auto == 'last'">
  is auto
</div>
```